# I need a way to keep track of many images

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a VueJs app that has many images and all the images are links to different websites. I am worried one of those websites remove an image and I don't notice my image being gone because of huge number of them. I can't check 500 images everyday. I prefer not to use Nuxt or Vuex but if they are options, I would be happy to try them. Also I don't want backend languages or code. Any thing is helpful.

Comment: https://www.deadlinkchecker.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're searching for a broken link checker.

You can use this npm package [broken-link-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/broken-link-checker) to verify the validity of each link, thus the presence or absence of each image and act in consequence.

Comment: Glad that I helped you sir. just mark my answer as correct please !